# how to access all buttons in every container

Tags: javascript

I want to assign an event listener for every button in every container,
but I don't want to  loop through the buttons first, because Firstly

I want to access the container to use hidden inputs to be passed as parameter to every event listener.

but this way the parameters of every button function will be over written.
In the end they all have the same parameter ( parameter of last item in the list).

```js
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.productsContainer');

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var id = products[i].getElementsByClassName('pr_id')[0].value;
  var price = products[i].getElementsByClassName('pr_price')[0].value;
  var Pname = products[i].getElementsByClassName('pr_name')[0].value
  var btn = products[i].getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openpopUp(id, price, Pname)
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="productCard">
    <img src="'.$row['Picture'].'">
    <h3><a href="productDetails.php?id='.$row['Product_ID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</a></h3>
    <h4>'.$row['price'].'</h4>
    <Button type="button" class="open">aa</Button>
    <input type="hidden" class="pr_id" id="producId" value="'.$row['Product_ID'].'">
    <input type="hidden" class="pr_name" name="productName" value="'.$row['Name'].'">
    <input type="hidden" class="pr_price" name="productPrice" value="'.$row['price'].'">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what `products` actually is? Or include its initialization

Comment: @prosach i added it in the first part of the code

Comment: use `const` instead of `var`

Comment: EITHER you have a mistake and you only have ONE productsContainer, then change my code to `document.querySelector('.productsContainer').addEventListener` OR you have many, then wrap them in a div with id mainContainer and use my code above as it is written

Comment: @mplungjan i changed var to const and it worked

Comment: this is better: `document.getElementById('mainContainer').addEventListener('click' (e) => { const tgt = e.target;  if (tgt.matches('button.open')) openpopUp(parent.querySelector('.pr_id').value, +parent.querySelector('.pr_price').value, parent.querySelector('.pr_name').value) })`

Comment: @mplungjan thats a very good code, thank u